# Datetime sorting is not working in react bootstrap table 2

Tags: reactjs, sorting, react-bootstrap, react-bootstrap-table

Am using react bootstrap table 2 in my react UI application.
In datetime column, sorting is enabled but the feature is not working. Am getting the table output value as 2019-12-02T15:46:40.000 and i have formatted to 15:46:40(HH:MM:ss). In Table it is displayed as HH:MM:ss. I see the table supports only sorting in alphabetical format.Is there any way to sort using custom function.

Appreciate your help.

Comment: The [documentation site shows an example of a custom sort function](http://allenfang.github.io/react-bootstrap-table/example.html#customsort_s)...

Comment: Already i have tried the custom sort as given in the below link.But no luck.
https://github.com/AllenFang/react-bootstrap-table/issues/1142